# Single_template for a custom post type created from a plugin is returning an empty page

Tags: plugin-development, filters

I'm trying to create a single template for the custom post type posts called 'press release' from a plugin.

This is the code I added to my plugin:

```
function single_press_release_template($single_template) {
     global $post;
     $plugin_path = plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ );
     if ($post->post_type == 'press_release') {
        if(file_exists($plugin_path . 'views/single-press_release.php')) {
            $single_template = $plugin_path . 'views/single-press_release.php';
            echo 'EXISTS! ' . $plugin_path . 'views/single-press_release.php';
        }
     }
     return $single_template;
}
add_filter( 'single_template', 'single_press_release_template');
```

The file `single-press_release.php` (located in the 'views' plugins directory) contains this code:

```
/**
 * Single Press Release
 *
 * @package WordPress
 */

<?php

echo 'Hello World';

?>
```

The result I get is a page without any main content (there is no 'hello world' text at all) but I can see the echo `'EXISTS! ' . $plugin_path . 'views/single-press_release.php'`:

[image: blank main content]

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

So, the template file is there, but it doesn't get called, even though your function looks good (to me) as [it does exactly what the codex says](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/single_template). The problem is therefore most probably caused by interference by your theme or another plugin that uses the same filter, overruling yours. You could solve that by giving your filter a higher priority:

```
add_filter ('single_template', 'single_press_release_template', 20 ,1);
```